# Combining Bind variables for webpage lookup

Tags: oracle, bind-variables

I have this sql that uses the same variable (:Item) for 3 different tables in the where clause. It runs fine in Oracle SQL developer. It pops up and asks for the Item and returns the correct data.
I want to create a web page using this sql to allow the user to lookup the Item. This is querying against an Oracle database. 
Is there a way to rewrite this so it combines the 3 :Items into 1?
Then I would use that as my search field for the web page.
I'm new to this so be kind.

```
SELECT ITEM_C.SEGMENT1 "Chain (Top) Item",
  ITEM_C.DESCRIPTION,
  ITEM_F.SEGMENT1 "Newer Item",
  ITEM_F.DESCRIPTION,
  item_t.SEGMENT1 "Older Item",
  item_t.DESCRIPTION "Older Description",
  ITEM_C.ITEM_TYPE TOP_ITEM_TYPE,
  ITEM_F.ITEM_TYPE NEWER_ITEM_TYPE,
  item_t.ITEM_TYPE Older_Item_Type,
  DOF.LINK_NUMBER,
  DOF.SUPERCESSION_TYPE,
  (SELECT fu.USER_NAME
  FROM apps.fnd_user fu
  WHERE fu.USER_ID = DOF.CREATED_BY
  ) "DOF Created By",
  DOF.CREATION_DATE "DOF Created",
  DOF.LAST_UPDATE_DATE "DOF Updated",
  item_t.CREATION_DATE "Older Created",
  item_t.LAST_UPDATE_DATE "Older Updated",
  ITEM_C.CREATION_DATE "Top Created",
  TRUNC(ITEM_C.CREATION_DATE - DOF.CREATION_DATE, 1) "Chain Lag",
  DECODE(
  (SELECT 1 FROM inv.mtl_system_items_b a WHERE a.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = ITEM_C.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
  AND a.ORGANIZATION_ID = 2470383
  ), NULL, 'No', 'Yes') "Top in P01",
  DECODE(
  (SELECT 1 FROM INV.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B a WHERE a.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = ITEM_C.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
  AND a.ORGANIZATION_ID = 98
  ), NULL, 'No', 'Yes') "Top in FTE",
  DECODE(
  (SELECT 1 FROM inv.mtl_system_items_b a WHERE a.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = ITEM_F.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
  AND a.ORGANIZATION_ID = 2470383
  ), NULL, 'No', 'Yes') "Newest in P01",
  DECODE(
  (SELECT 1 FROM INV.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B a WHERE a.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = ITEM_F.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
  AND a.ORGANIZATION_ID = 98
  ), NULL, 'No', 'Yes') "Newest in FTE",
  DECODE(
  (SELECT 1 FROM inv.mtl_system_items_b a WHERE a.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = item_t.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
  AND a.ORGANIZATION_ID = 2470383
  ), NULL, 'No', 'Yes') "Oldest in P01",
  DECODE(
  (SELECT 1 FROM inv.mtl_system_items_b a WHERE a.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = item_t.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
  AND a.ORGANIZATION_ID = 98
  ), NULL, 'No', 'Yes') "Oldest in FTE",
  ITEM_C.PURCHASING_ENABLED_FLAG "Top Purchasing Enabled",
  ITEM_F.PURCHASING_ENABLED_FLAG "Newer Purchasing Enabled",
  item_t.PURCHASING_ENABLED_FLAG "Older Purchasing Enabled",
  ITEM_C.FIXED_LOT_MULTIPLIER CHAIN_FLM,
  ITEM_F.FIXED_LOT_MULTIPLIER NEWER_FLM,
  item_t.FIXED_LOT_MULTIPLIER Older_FLM,
  SysDate "Current Date"
FROM IKNDOF.IKN_DOF_ITEM_CHAINS DOF
LEFT OUTER JOIN INV.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B ITEM_F
ON DOF.FROM_ITEM_ID = ITEM_F.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
AND ITEM_F.ORGANIZATION_ID = 86
LEFT OUTER JOIN INV.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B ITEM_C
ON DOF.CHAIN_ITEM_ID = ITEM_C.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
AND ITEM_C.ORGANIZATION_ID = 86
LEFT OUTER JOIN inv.mtl_system_items_b item_t
ON DOF.TO_ITEM_ID = item_t.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
AND item_t.ORGANIZATION_ID = 86
WHERE 1 = 1
AND DOF.CHAIN_ITEM_ID     IN
  (SELECT DISTINCT df.CHAIN_ITEM_ID
  FROM inv.mtl_system_items_b topi,
    inv.mtl_system_items_b fri,
    inv.mtl_system_items_b toi,
    ikndof.ikn_dof_item_chains df
  WHERE df.FROM_ITEM_ID    = fri.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID(+)
  AND df.TO_ITEM_ID        = toi.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID(+)
  AND df.CHAIN_ITEM_ID     = topi.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID(+)
  AND fri.ORGANIZATION_ID  = 86
  AND toi.ORGANIZATION_ID  = 86
  AND topi.ORGANIZATION_ID = 86
  AND (fri.SEGMENT1 LIKE :Item
  OR toi.SEGMENT1 LIKE :Item
  OR topi.SEGMENT1 LIKE :Item)
  )
ORDER BY "Chain (Top) Item",
  DOF.LINK_NUMBER
```

Thanks,   Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options here -

Option 1. put this query in your web page using the syntax according to the scripting language you use. This option is not recommended.

Option 2. Create Stored Procedure (SP) in Oracle and call it in your webpage. This is much better option because

a.) SP is compiled hence runs faster

b.) it can be re-used by multiple pages/clients.

c.) if the query changes you only need to change it in one place - SP.

Below is the Stored Procedure I put together for you, it should compile in your IDE, hopefully without modifications.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE yourdb.yourproc
(
        i_search            IN varchar2,
        o_return_cursor     OUT  GLOBAL.GenericCursorType
) AS
BEGIN


    OPEN o_return_cursor FOR 
SELECT ITEM_C.SEGMENT1 "Chain (Top) Item",
  ITEM_C.DESCRIPTION,
  ITEM_F.SEGMENT1 "Newer Item",
  ITEM_F.DESCRIPTION,
  item_t.SEGMENT1 "Older Item",
  item_t.DESCRIPTION "Older Description",
  ITEM_C.ITEM_TYPE TOP_ITEM_TYPE,
  ITEM_F.ITEM_TYPE NEWER_ITEM_TYPE,
  item_t.ITEM_TYPE Older_Item_Type,
  DOF.LINK_NUMBER,
  DOF.SUPERCESSION_TYPE,
  (SELECT fu.USER_NAME
  FROM apps.fnd_user fu
  WHERE fu.USER_ID = DOF.CREATED_BY
  ) "DOF Created By",
  DOF.CREATION_DATE "DOF Created",
  DOF.LAST_UPDATE_DATE "DOF Updated",
  item_t.CREATION_DATE "Older Created",
  item_t.LAST_UPDATE_DATE "Older Updated",
  ITEM_C.CREATION_DATE "Top Created",
  TRUNC(ITEM_C.CREATION_DATE - DOF.CREATION_DATE, 1) "Chain Lag",
  DECODE(
  (SELECT 1 FROM inv.mtl_system_items_b a WHERE a.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = ITEM_C.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
  AND a.ORGANIZATION_ID = 2470383
  ), NULL, 'No', 'Yes') "Top in P01",
  DECODE(
  (SELECT 1 FROM INV.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B a WHERE a.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = ITEM_C.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
  AND a.ORGANIZATION_ID = 98
  ), NULL, 'No', 'Yes') "Top in FTE",
  DECODE(
  (SELECT 1 FROM inv.mtl_system_items_b a WHERE a.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = ITEM_F.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
  AND a.ORGANIZATION_ID = 2470383
  ), NULL, 'No', 'Yes') "Newest in P01",
  DECODE(
  (SELECT 1 FROM INV.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B a WHERE a.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = ITEM_F.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
  AND a.ORGANIZATION_ID = 98
  ), NULL, 'No', 'Yes') "Newest in FTE",
  DECODE(
  (SELECT 1 FROM inv.mtl_system_items_b a WHERE a.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = item_t.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
  AND a.ORGANIZATION_ID = 2470383
  ), NULL, 'No', 'Yes') "Oldest in P01",
  DECODE(
  (SELECT 1 FROM inv.mtl_system_items_b a WHERE a.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = item_t.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
  AND a.ORGANIZATION_ID = 98
  ), NULL, 'No', 'Yes') "Oldest in FTE",
  ITEM_C.PURCHASING_ENABLED_FLAG "Top Purchasing Enabled",
  ITEM_F.PURCHASING_ENABLED_FLAG "Newer Purchasing Enabled",
  item_t.PURCHASING_ENABLED_FLAG "Older Purchasing Enabled",
  ITEM_C.FIXED_LOT_MULTIPLIER CHAIN_FLM,
  ITEM_F.FIXED_LOT_MULTIPLIER NEWER_FLM,
  item_t.FIXED_LOT_MULTIPLIER Older_FLM,
  SysDate "Current Date"
FROM IKNDOF.IKN_DOF_ITEM_CHAINS DOF
LEFT OUTER JOIN INV.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B ITEM_F
ON DOF.FROM_ITEM_ID = ITEM_F.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
AND ITEM_F.ORGANIZATION_ID = 86
LEFT OUTER JOIN INV.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B ITEM_C
ON DOF.CHAIN_ITEM_ID = ITEM_C.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
AND ITEM_C.ORGANIZATION_ID = 86
LEFT OUTER JOIN inv.mtl_system_items_b item_t
ON DOF.TO_ITEM_ID = item_t.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
AND item_t.ORGANIZATION_ID = 86
WHERE 1 = 1
AND DOF.CHAIN_ITEM_ID     IN
  (SELECT DISTINCT df.CHAIN_ITEM_ID
  FROM inv.mtl_system_items_b topi,
    inv.mtl_system_items_b fri,
    inv.mtl_system_items_b toi,
    ikndof.ikn_dof_item_chains df
  WHERE df.FROM_ITEM_ID    = fri.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID(+)
  AND df.TO_ITEM_ID        = toi.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID(+)
  AND df.CHAIN_ITEM_ID     = topi.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID(+)
  AND fri.ORGANIZATION_ID  = 86
  AND toi.ORGANIZATION_ID  = 86
  AND topi.ORGANIZATION_ID = 86
  AND (fri.SEGMENT1 LIKE i_search
  OR toi.SEGMENT1 LIKE i_search
  OR topi.SEGMENT1 LIKE i_search)
  )
ORDER BY "Chain (Top) Item",
  DOF.LINK_NUMBER ;


EXCEPTION
    WHEN  OTHERS THEN 

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(SQLCODE)||'  yourproc WHEN OTHERS  '); 
END; -- Procedure 
/
```

Comment: Thanks Leonid, I don't have rights to create a stored procedure. I'll see if I can have the admins do it for me and test it out.